# If you disclose an invention, are you still able to file for trade secrecy?

Tags: intellectual-property

Say I have an invention that I have already disclosed. I am now trying to seek a form of Intellectual Property for it. Am I still able to seek trade secrecy since I've already disclosed about the invention? If I can't file for trade secrecy, am I still able to file for a patent?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it does not seem to be about academia.

Comment: Actually, I think this is very appropriate for academia, since it's more likely that an academic could disclose something that is later realized to be patentable—because academics present their work much more often, and may not have an internal review process.

Comment: I concur with @aeismail: misguided idea leads to good question with terse answer.  Voting to reopen.

Comment: I agree with @aeismail's comments. My industry employers always had policies and procedures in place to protect trade secrets.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. Trade secrets are not registered. Voluntary disclosure pretty much destroys trade secret status. If you want to have a trade secret, don't tell anyone without a non-disclosure agreement in place. A patent may be available to you depending on your jurisdiction. Consult an attorney in the location where you want to protect your invention.

Comment: Do the very late couple of downvoters want to comment?

Comment: This is correct for USA jurisdiction.  Trade secrets have an absolute erosion if disclosed.  Even if involuntarily, if the person harmed by the disclosure takes no action (and quickly), then they have no claim.